# como puedo desaparecer varios jLabel y JtextField dependiendo de la opcion que se ingrese en un JComboBox

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Hola buenas soy algo novata en java, uso netbeans y me gustaría ver si me podrían ayudar hacer que al seleccionar un JComboBox  con 3 tipos de calculos diferentes se desaparezcan los JLabel y los JTextFiel que no pertecen a ese tipo de prestamo sera que puedan ayudarme haciendo un ejemplo simple de nose 3 colores diferentes y que desaparescan los JtexFiel y los JLabal que no pertecen a ese tipo de color, se los agradeceria de verdad
**se por ejemplo como bloquear los Jtextfiel para que solo se ingrese el que se selecciono, pero vi un video donde alguien los desaparecia por completo y me gustaria ver si podrian  ayudarme a como hacerlo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imagenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y fasilites el uso del mismo, También  es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Si solo quieres tener 1 panel y que esos JLabel y JTextField vayan desapareciendo, usa el evento addActionListener del JComboBox, verifica que tipo de String esta seleccionado y ya teniendo las instancias de los componentes, oculta los que no necesites o aparece los que si necesites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes agregar el `addActionListener` del JComboBox e implementar el método `actionPerformed`, de la siguiente manera:

```
public OcultarComponentes() {        
        cmbColores.removeAllItems();
        cmbColores.addItem("");
        cmbColores.addItem("Azul");
        cmbColores.addItem("Rojo");
        cmbColores.addItem("Amarillo");
        cmbColores.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                String s = (String) cmbColores.getSelectedItem();
                switch (s) {
                    case "Azul":
                        lblAmarillo.setVisible(false);txtAmarillo.setVisible(false);
                        lblRojo.setVisible(false);txtRojo.setVisible(false);
                        lblAzul.setVisible(true);txtAzul.setVisible(true); 
                        break;
                    case "Rojo":
                        lblAmarillo.setVisible(false);txtAmarillo.setVisible(false);
                        lblAzul.setVisible(false);txtAzul.setVisible(false); 
                        lblRojo.setVisible(true);txtRojo.setVisible(true);
                        break;
                    case "Amarillo":
                        lblAzul.setVisible(false);txtAzul.setVisible(false);
                        lblRojo.setVisible(false);txtRojo.setVisible(false);
                        lblAmarillo.setVisible(true);txtAmarillo.setVisible(true);
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: muchas gracias , igual funcionaria con 3 if verdad y  no un switch

Comment: exacto, el if cumple lo mismo que el switch

Comment: ok muchas gracias